# How can I Focus next input on Enter with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx

I am using TextField (MaterialUI). When I click on enter key (google Keyboard) i need to set focus on next field.

How can i do this with reactJS?
Can you help me?

Comment: I would recommend you do not implement such behavior. By default you should use tab to go to the next field and enter is used to submit form. If you do what you are going to do you will confuse a lot of users.

Comment: @Arseniy-II, I'm developing PWA. So, I need this comportment. In a web application, really, i don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Created Example:
Using: TextField  inputRef and array of refs:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3kj6x (Tested in desktop)